# How to share record access to customer community licensed users

Tags: community, customer-community, calendar, sharing-sets, fullcalendar

Primarily, I am trying to show custom object(Calendar_Events__c) records to customer community licensed users based on the condition/tag such as Tag = Group A, Group B

.i.e users will have a Multi-Select Picklist field that contains values such as Group A, Group B, Group C, etc and the Calendar_Events__c will also have a Multi-Select Picklist field that contains Group A, Group B, etc.

When the Calendar_Events__c tag is set to Group A, the users with a similar tag should be able to see this record on communities.

I am **not** using the Customer community plus license, so apex sharing is not possible here.

Also, these records will be shown on a calendar.

*If possible please suggest me any **app exchange** application that suits my requirement.*

Comment: Customer Community licenses cannot access the Campaign object.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5

Comment: thanks @DavidCheng for your immediate response, I have modified the question based on your comment. Please check it once.

Comment: also used sharing sets, unable to access records that are linked to User's contact's account's parent account. If this is possible please guide me.

Comment: Please provide your thoughts here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310542/how-to-share-custom-object-records-to-community-users