# How to share custom Object records to community users?

Tags: customer-community, calendar, sharing-sets, fullcalendar

[image]
Is there any way to share Standard / Custom object records to Customer Community Licensed users.

**The different records to different users** based on some conditions.

As we are using Customer community user Licenses, apex sharing is not possible.

Please let me know for any alternative solution for this.

I tried sharing sets, but I don't know whether it is possible for my case scenario as shown in the chart.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use Sharing Sets.
Find more information here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_setting_light_users.htm&language=en_us&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

Example of sharing set:
[image]

Sharing with Sharing sets are somewhat limited, and it does not have the same flexibility as sharing rules or APEX sharing.

You could use sharing sets to share cases related to accounts the customer has access to or owns.

A sharing sets can only apply to one profile, so you have make a decision on the sharing model of those users that use the customer community license.
Best regards,
Christian.

Comment: hey, Christian, I found your comments useful but somehow it  is removed, so I request you to please update your answer by providing the suggestion of  relating 1 contact to multiple accounts